# python multiindex assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have an issue with multiindex assignment and will like to store values as highlighted below

I have a function called **df_x** that is a dataframe and looks like

```
print df_x

serial    P1       P2       P3

5         21       32       35
10        33       45       76
15        65       99       563
```

I will like it to store as follows

For example for  **level[0]**  of value **alpha**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns= df_x.columns)
```

it should create a *multiindex on* **df1** so that

print **df1** should look like

```
print df1


alpha    serial    5     10    15

         P1        21    33    65

         P2        32    45    99

         P3        35    76    563
```

However, I am struggling to create multiindex on original df_x dataframe

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 0**

```
pd.concat([df_x], keys=['alpha'])

serial    P1  P2   P3
alpha 5   21  32   35
      10  33  45   76
      15  65  99  563
```

---

**Option 1**

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df_x.values,
    [['alpha'] * len(df_x), df_x.index],
    df_x.columns
)

serial    P1  P2   P3
alpha 5   21  32   35
      10  33  45   76
      15  65  99  563
```

---

**Option 2**

```
df_x.set_index(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [['alpha'], df_x.index], names=[None, df_x.index.name]
    )
)
```

---

**Setup**

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame(**{
    'columns': pd.Index(['P1', 'P2', 'P3'], name='serial'),
    'data': [[21, 32, 35], [33, 45, 76], [65, 99, 563]],
    'index': [5, 10, 15]})
```

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate that.